# arithmatic operations and labelling in ggplot or R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a file that looks like this

```
2 3 LOGIC:A
2 5 LOGIC:A
3 4 LOGIC:Z
```

I plotted column 1 on x axis vs column 2 on y with column 3 acting as a legend

```
ggplot(Data, aes(V1, V2, col = V3)) + geom_point()
```

However is it possible in ggplot itself to subtract column 2 and column 1 and label the top 10 highest absolute difference rows of this subtraction with column 3 values on each scatter point. I dont want to label the entire dataset. Just the top 10 highest deltas

Comment: in a scaterplot on axes would be `(v2-v1)` but what would be the other axes?

Comment: One axis is v2 and the other is still v1. I just want to do v2-v1 absolute value and label the top 10 biggest (v2-v1) on the same scatter plot. Label comes from column 3

Comment: let's make an example, `v2=5`, and `v1=1`. So one of the positions which should be shown is `(5,1)`, but if we consider `(5-1,?)` then you still need to fill the `?` unless you want to show the absolute difference only on 1 axes. Am i right?

Comment: I dont want to show the absolute anywhere. (5,1) point still exists. Behind the scenes I want to be able to do (5-1=4) for all points.. say you get subtraction values as 1 2 -3 4 7 8 for 6 different points on the original plot. Now I want to take the 4 biggest differences and annotaate column 3 corresponding to the 4 biggest differences on the same original (5,1) plot. So, since difference of 5 minus 1 is 4 and this is among the biggest differences then on the point lieing on (5,1) I want to label the column 3 corresponding to this from original dataset

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if you original dataframe is Data):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Data$sub <- abs(Data$V2 - Data$V1)

Data2<- Data %>%
  top_n(10,sub)

ggplot()+ geom_text(data=Data2,aes(V1,V2-0.1,label=V3))+
    geom_point(data=Data,aes(V1,V2))
```

With the library dplyr you can filter the top values of a dataframe.
You can change "0.1" for a better value in your plot

Comment: Does this take the absolute value of v2 minus v1

Comment: I've added the absolute value

Comment: can you explain `col=v3` and  `geom_text()`? The OP asked for scatterplot. Also, where did you used the `sub`?

Comment: But he want the value of the V3 column on each scatter point, if you use also geom_point its going to be below the text. And the col is not necessary, only if you want different colors by label.

Comment: Thanks. However I want to keep the original dataset as well. Say we have 100 points on the scatter plot. I want to label the top 10 biggest differences while keeping the rest 90 just as points and without any label. Also, the points are replaced by the actual column 3 text in the plot. I want to be able to keep the points while labelling them on a little above the actual point..